# Need help from a drupal expert

Tags: drupal

I have a websites www.example.com which is a druapal 6 site. Works well, never had any issues.

I have written a stand alone PHP app that I don't have the time or the requirement to convert to a drupal module.

I want to host the app at www.example.com/myPhpApp/*

Will this have any conflicts with the drupal site? what would happen if I created a drupal page at the same address?

Thanks so much in advnced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't confuse Drupal as long as you don't make paths inside of the new folder. 
If you have a .htaccess file that handles requests, most likely that Drupal cannot take over the page. 
If you have a folder and a Drupal path, folder will be the first choice.